# How to get timezone name in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to fetch current timezone name `Asia/Calcutta` in Flutter/Dart?

`DateTime.now().timeZoneName` fetches String `IST`.
`DateTime.now().timeZoneOffset` fetches Duration `5:30:00.000000`.

`Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone` gives the desired result, `Asia/Calcutta`, in JavaScript.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: IST is the standard abbreviation for your time zone, and +05:30 is the offset for that time zone. Beyond that, every time zone has a potentially large number of different "names" for that time zone, and which one you want specifically might be somewhat arbitrary. For example, for your particular time zone, how would Dart know whether you wanted "Asia/Calcutta", "Asia/Columbo", or "Asia/Kolkata"?

Comment: @Abion47 How does javascript know whether I wanted "Asia/Calcutta" or "Asia/Columbo"?

Comment: I Imagine it either chooses arbitrarily or it takes your location data and makes its best guess. All I can tell you is to [find a package that does something similar](https://pub.dev/packages/timezone) and good luck.

Comment: @Abion47 I just tested on native Android using Java, I was able to fetch "Asia/Kolkata" using `java.util.TimeZone.getDefault().getID()`. I think it probably deals with System's DateTime settings.

Comment: So it's as rigorous a procedure as it would be just making a `Map` object that takes time zone abbreviations and arbitrarily returns an IANA time zone locale name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the package [flutter_native_timezone](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_timezone), easy to setup and use.

import the package

`import 'package:flutter_native_timezone/flutter_native_timezone.dart';`

and use as

`timezone = await FlutterNativeTimezone.getLocalTimezone();`

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_timezone/example

Comment: nice find. writing [custom platform-specific code](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels) does the job well. for [android](https://github.com/pinkfish/flutter_native_timezone/blob/master/android/src/main/kotlin/com/whelksoft/flutter_native_timezone/FlutterNativeTimezonePlugin.kt) and for [ios](https://github.com/pinkfish/flutter_native_timezone/blob/master/ios/Classes/FlutterNativeTimezonePlugin.m).  
it would be awesome to see flutter adding an attribute in `DateTime.now()` to get this value.

Answer (score 1):

I got the timezone fixed in Flutter this way.

```
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;
static const platform = const MethodChannel('channel NAME');
Future<void> _configureLocalTimeZone() async {
    tz.initializeTimeZones();
    var locations = tz.timeZoneDatabase.locations;
    final locationName = tz.getLocation(locations.keys.first); //Asia/Calcutta
    tz.setLocalLocation(locationName);
  }
```

Calling

```
await _configureLocalTimeZone();
```